# Why can't I delete both account and content when cancelling a user account, in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, nodes

Before, drupal 7 core, and in drupal 6, a contrib module called user_delete,  had this 4th option in deleting user accounts settings:

"Delete the account and its content." (drupal 7) and

"delete a user and delete all submitted content including nodes and comments" (drupal 6)

But this option seems unavailable in drupal 8 core. Why?

I really want both account and content deleted. The option they offer would force me to periodically delete the unpublished content of the removed account via cron.

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting content requires an access check, and as such the *Delete the account and its content.* option can't be selected as the default. I presume this is because a user can have access to cancel their own account, but not be able to select the method, and there's no mechanism implemented to provide a fallback for the default.

You'll still see it when cancelling an individual account, provided you have the *administer users* permission:

[image]

If you'd rather get control of that process yourself you can implement [`hook_user_cancel_methods_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel_methods_alter/8.5.x) to remove or change the access check.

Comment: You are clarifying the existing logical mechanism well, but what I don't understand why this method has been chosen in D8. 

Is there no way in D8 to have an auth. user "Delete his account and its content.", without having other cancelling methods, just the button "cancel account"? I mean, by configuration in the admin's interface (I'm sure it's possible by code)

It just seems to such an obvious demand, allowing a user to fully remove himself incl content, that IMHO, it should be configurable in the interface, like in Drupal7 (where I spent like 3 mins on the subject and it just worked).

Comment: Absolutely there’s a way - remove the access property using the hook. Then it’ll be exactly the same as it was in D7. The access check was introduced as a security improvement, if you don’t need it you can just get rid of it with a few lines of code, no harm done. If you think it’s a regression, just open an issue on the core issue queue. They’ll either agree and change it, or (more likely) explain in more detail what the motivation and requirements were for the D8 version

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks a lot. I'll just use the hook to override it then. (I'll remove my other "answer").

Comment: It appeared this would not work, because of some batch operation restriction.. When clicking the cancel account link in the confirmation email, a batch screen appears, but frozen.. It said "Initializing", but never starts to actually remove account and nodes.

Comment: Since I did not really wanted to use the email confirmation anyway, I chose to use this module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/user_cancel_immediate ) , which circumvents the batch issue. It is working well now.